# Theoretical framework of comparing linguistic landscapes of an urban and a rural location

Tags: english, sociolinguistics

I am working on a thesis and I chose a topic about comparing linguistic landscapes of two locations. One is urban with international community and relatively economically privileged class of the country. The second one is surrounded by villages and customers are semi-literate, many of them from surrounding villages. I am thinking of applying social action theory as a theoretical framework. But the social action theories like hermeneutic etc. do not seem suitable. The research context is Pakistan; the comparison of two locations which are Islamabad and a nearby town Fateh Jang. Kindly suggest me what could be a suitable theoretical framework for this kind of research.

My subject for my doctorate is English Language Teaching.

Comment: Ethnolinguistics and/or sociolinguistics. How many languages are spoken in the groups you're tracking? How many hours of recording do you plan to do? What about data analysis?

Comment: Sociolinguistics. Many languages are spoken but my focus is on only two: English and Urdu because other languages do not appear in written form in linguistic landscapes. It is not recording. More than 500 photos will be collected from four business hubs. Three hubs are from urban area while the one is from rural area. Almost all business sectors will be covered and then the data will be analysed quantitatively. However, interviews of 10 language teachers will be conducted to see the implications of linguistic landscapes on ELT. This data will be analysed qualitatively.

Comment: Oh, by _landscapes_ you mean actual visual landscapes in photographs. I was thinking it was metaphoric. What do photographs have to do with language?